# Can't find an element via document.getElementById even though it should be there

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, chart.js

I am trying to find an element using `document.getElementById`, but right now I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

The function where this line is written, is only called when the google maps is 'idle' so the element should be present in the document at that point.

I am guessing for some reason the html is not loaded yet, when the function is called. So I should probably change the `addListenerOnce` function in some way. I have tried replacing 'idle' with 'load' but that did not seem to work.

```
initializeDoughnut(map) {
    console.log(this.name.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    var doughnutMarker = createHTMLMapMarker({
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng((this.latlng.lat()+0.00006),(this.latlng.lng()-0.00007)),
        map: map,
        html: `<div id="canvas-holder`+this.name.replace(/\s/g, '')+`" class="doughnut">
          <canvas id="chart-area`+this.name.replace(/\s/g, '')+`" width="110" height="110" />
      </div>
      `
      })
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        console.log("Map is idle at " + this.name);
        this.loaddoughnut();
    }.bind(this));
}

loaddoughnut() {
    var colors = ['#27AE60','#E74C3C'];

    var donutOptions = {
      cutoutPercentage: 80,
      legend: {display: false}
    };

    var donutData1 = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,2),
          borderWidth: 0,
          data: [0, 0, 100],
          label: "Doughnut 1"
        },
      ]
    };

    var config = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: donutData1,
      options: donutOptions

    }
    console.log(document);
    console.log(document.getElementById("canvas-holder"+this.name.replace(/\s/g, '')));
    console.log(document.getElementById("chart-area"+this.name.replace(/\s/g, '')));
    // Line which gives the error
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area"+this.name.replace(/\s/g, '')).getContext("2d");
    this.doughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, config); 
}
```

Comment: And where is your HTML? And how/when is this script loaded?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.